# Как настроить клик видимого элемента в Android?

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin, android-sdk

Имеется кнопка `close` в `RelativeLayout`. Этот `RelativeLayout` имеет наследника в виде `ScrollView`. Когда `ScrollView` начинает покрывать кнопку она должна становиться некликабельной, но пока эту кнопку видно она должна оставаться кликабельной. Я использую библиотеки [Carbon](https://github.com/ZieIony/Carbon) и [BounceScrollView](https://github.com/woxingxiao/BounceScrollView)

```
<carbon.widget.RelativeLayout>

    <!-- some content -->

    <carbon.widget.Button
        android:id="@+id/close"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/close"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="21dp"
        app:carbon_elevation="0dp"/>


    <com.xw.repo.widget.BounceScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:scrollbars="none">

        <carbon.widget.RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="110dp">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В таком случае лучше использовать `NestedScrollView` в паре с `CollapsingToolbarLayout`

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="126dp"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/cyan"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar">

        <carbon.widget.RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

            <!-- content of AppBarLayout-->

        </carbon.widget.RelativeLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/nested_scroll_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:overScrollMode="never"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    app:layout_behavior=
    "com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior">

    <!-- content of NestedScrollView -->

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]